# Get the content of category when i click on a div | Laravel

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel

I work on laravel 7 and i have a problem, i want to display the content of the product of a category in ajax.

I dont know why but the i cant grab the id of my category in ajax...
I want to show the product form each category when i click on the div, if dont click on the category div i want to show nothing.

This is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Mail;
use App\User;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;
use App\Tva;
use App\Pricepallet;
use App\Warehouse;
use App\WarehouseProduct;
use Session;

class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex() {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('front.pages.index', compact('categories','products'));
    }

    public function getProducts($id){
        if($id!=0){
            $products = Category::find($id)->products()->select('id', 'title')->get()->toArray();
        }else{
            $products = Product::all()->toArray();
        }
        return response()->json($products);
    }

}
```

This is my view:

```
@extends('front.app')
@section('title', 'Administration | BDCE')
@section('content')
<div class="panier-pc">
    <table class="table-panier-pc">
        <thead class="thead-panier-pc">
            <tr>
                <th>Ma Commande</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">On commence par choisir sa ville:</p>
                    <form>
                        <input class="input-rech" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Rechercher ma ville...">
                    </form>
                    <br />
                    <div class="texte-panier-pc">
                    <p class="texte-panier-pc">Format:</p>
                    <p class="texte-panier-pc">Quantité:</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="texte-total-panier-pc">Total:</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="encart-ville">
        <table class="table-encart-ville">
            <thead class="thead-encart-ville">
                <tr>
                    <th>Ma Commande</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <form>
                        <input class="input-rech" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Rechercher ma ville...">
                    </form>
                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="encart-produit-pc">
        <table class="table-encart-produit-pc">
            <thead class="thead-encart-produit-pc">
                <tr>
                    <th>Mes Articles</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div class="container-pc">
                    <h2>Je choisis ma catégorie</h2>
                    <div class="colonne_categorie">
                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                            @foreach ($category->products as $product)
                            <div name="category" id="{{ $category->id }}" class="categories_produits"><img src="{{ url('/img') }}/{{ $category->image }}" alt="{{ $category->title }}"> <span class="categories_produits_texte">{{ $category->title }}</span></div><br>
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="colonne_produit">
                    <h2>Je choisis mon type de bois de chauffage</h2><br /><br />
                    @foreach($products as $product)
                    <div name="product" class="categories_produits">
                        <span class="categories_produits_texte">{{ $product->title }}</span>
                    </div><br>
                    @endforeach
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('div[name=category]').on('click', function () {
        var selected = $(this).find(":selected").attr('id');
        $.ajax({
                    url: '/category/'+selected+'/products/',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',

            }).done(function (data) {

                var select = $('div[name=product]');
                select.empty();
                $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                    select.append(key.id + value.title);
                });
                console.log("success");
        })
    });
});
</script>
@endsection
```

I have make the route of course.
I think this is a problem with my JS code.

Thx a lot

Comment: Yes i caught but i dont get the id, see my image: https://i.imgur.com/5nyfyon.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- You cannot use the name attribute for a , use the class instead.
- The id of you div is not unique in this case, place the div outside the inner loop
- There are also no input tags in your loop to be selected.

So something like this

```
<div id="{{ $category->id }}" class="categories_produits category">
<img src="{{ url('/img') }}/{{ $category->image }}" alt="{{ $category->title }}">
<span class="categories_produits_texte">{{ $category->title }}</span>
@foreach ($category->products as $product)
    <input> //place the inputs to select here
@endforeach
</div><br>
```

and then

```
$('.category').on('click', function () {....
```

Comment: Thank you, i have make the update but i cannot grab the id is not working you can see on the screen: https://i.imgur.com/5nyfyon.png

Comment: i just noticed you have multiple divs with the same id in your foreach loop, id must be unique.

Comment: and no input to be selected within that loop

Comment: ok, where can i putting the id of my category ? Thx

Comment: outside the inner foreach, and then you need input to select inside that loop (I've edited my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `children`

```
var selected = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
```

instead of

```
var selected = $(this).find(":selected").attr('id');
```

Comment: Thx but is not working i can get the id see my image: https://i.imgur.com/5nyfyon.png